# TexturePacker alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any sprite sheets editor like [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) ? I have been searching a lot on the web but I did not find a similar/equivalent tools.

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/texturepacker/ "We do not have any TexturePacker alternatives for Linux in our database." so probably not >:)

Comment: You did see that they provide a Ubuntu installer?

Comment: @Rinzwind: They provide debian package for ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: @Herks if it's just a case of versioning, give the 11.04 chance a shot. **Edit:** Just tried it and it does work in 12.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are providing debian installer files from their website.

- Ubuntu 32: http://www.codeandweb.com/download/texturepacker/2.4.0/TexturePacker-2.4.0-ubuntu32.deb
- Ubuntu 64: http://www.codeandweb.com/download/texturepacker/2.4.0/TexturePacker-2.4.0-ubuntu64.deb

The image they use to show they have an Ubuntu download suggests it is for 11.04 but that does not mean you can not install it in 11.10, 12.04, 12.10 or 13.04. Let Ubuntu Software Center open the file and see if it installs.

If this works... no need for an alternative.
If not please add it into your question and we can try to work from there ;)

Answer (score 0):

If we want texture-packer (or even spine) like abilities, the best free tool out there would be synfigstudio. synfigstudio is an animation tool which can be used to create hierarchical skeletons that can be animated using twining and other cool features. So you can create cool looking animated renders of frames - which you can then stitch together through some other automation, say, gimp script-fu or even ImageMagick to form a sprite sheet.

See http://www.synfig.org/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this

https://gutils.com/

This is a web-based application. All your data is stored in your browser storage

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1227937)